# Periodic Work Request not executing doWork in Work Manager

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm trying to get data from a remote url periodically using `PeriodicWorkRequest` in `WorkManager`. I have implemented the logic, the issue here is that i don't get any response from the `Worker`.

However it seems to call `doWork()` at first launch, but it doesn't get data from the network call. I am surprised that when i use `OneTimeWorkRequest` i get a success result from `doWork()` and the data from server as well.

what could i be doing wrong?

code below:

**Worker Class**

```
public class WorkerClass extends Worker {

private Context context;
public static final String EXTRA_WORKER_CLASS = "extra_tag";

public SpecialOffer(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    Log.d("WORKER_PERIOD", "started");
    String url = "https://sampleurl/get.php";
    //Volley synchronous call
    RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, future, future);
    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);

    try {
        String response = future.get();
        Data data = new Data.Builder()
                .putString(EXTRA_SPECIAL_CARS, response)
                .build();
        setOutputData(data);
        Log.d("WORKER_RESPONSE", response);
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        return Result.FAILURE;
    }
}
}
```

**Method to call task**

```
public void callTask(){
     PeriodicWorkRequest periodicRequest =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerClass.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                        .addTag("SPECIAL_OFFER")
                        .build();

        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("SPECIAL_OFFER",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicRequest);

        workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(periodicRequest.getId())
                .observe(getActivity(), workInfo -> {
                    Log.d("WORKER_PERIOD", "observed");
                    // Do something with the status
                    if (workInfo != null && workInfo.getState().isFinished()) {
                        Log.d("WORKER_PERIOD", "observed");
                        String ava = workInfo.getOutputData().getString(SpecialOffer.EXTRA_SPECIAL_CARS);
                        if (ava.equals("available")) {
                            showSpecialOffer(true);
                        } else {
                            showSpecialOffer(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: You should try it with `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE` policy.

Comment: Not working still, and why did you suggest REPLACE policy

Comment: I thought that `replace` policy replace your worker if it's already exists instead of `keep` will simply ignore it. One more thing you can try is providing **backoff criteria** to your `worker`, so that if it failed to run again then it can try after given criteria. I had same issues but fixed by given workarounds. Let me know if it still persist. We will try something else for you.

Comment: Ok I tried out Result.RETRY so it could retry if it failed, that doesn't work too. I think the issue is with PeriodicWorkRequest not returning FINISHED status of the task. You can look up this similar issue on github https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager/issues/75

Comment: Given the nature of the work you want to do (download something from the network) I would probably use a ListenableWorker and a ResolvableFuture that have been introduced in one of the last alpha of WorkManager. You can find some example [in this video around minute 11](https://youtu.be/83a4rYXsDs0?t=680). BTW, what the full video, if you plan to use WorkManager it's a treasure chest of information.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [PeriodicWorkRequest Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.html)

> The normal lifecycle of a PeriodicWorkRequest is ENQUEUED -> RUNNING -> ENQUEUED. By definition, periodic work cannot terminate in a succeeded or failed state, since it must recur. It can only terminate if explicitly cancelled

So when you do`workInfo.getState().isFinished()` in `.observe` it always returns `false`
because [.isFinished() method documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkInfo.State.html#isFinished) says:

> returns true for SUCCEEDED, FAILED, and * CANCELLED states